# Java Text Field Input Issue

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

So I'm trying to have users type in an answer to the question via a text field, but the way I have it set up, the name field is only being stored inside the ActionListener Class and not the QName class. I've checked by trying to output Name using the Name() function. Does anyone have any ideas on how I can pull out the info and store it into QName's name field? Thanks in advance

[Code for my QName function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lz5T.png)
[Code showing null output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qDmf.png)

Comment: Do not post pictures of your code. Images can get deleted and links can go stale. Instead, copy the code from your IDE and paste it into the question. Click the "edit" link under the text of your question to make changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your `name` field is null is because typing in your textfield doesn't generate any events that are caught by the associated listener.

You seem to have attached an `ActionListener` directly to your `JTextField`. The more typical (and for your purposes, the more correct) implementation is to associate the listener to a button in your QName object.

To fix your code, you're going to have to create a button. Let's assume you call it "OK". Then associate an `ActionListener` to the button instead of the textfield. Then your user can type a character name and click OK. In turn, your listener will detect the button press and set `name` to the contents of the textfield.

I'd post sample code, but I'm not going to key in all the code from your picture (this is another reason why you don't post pictures).